# Mongodb: how do you set a field value inside a nested array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have an array of objects in my Mongodb api that holds some company data inside each company object there is another array which holds the posts. I want to be able to find the company by id then find a post inside the posts array by id and update the column_index value. I'm able to get the company by id then the post by id but then I need to be able to change the column_index value of that post.

Here's the collection in my database:

```
[ 
    { 
        _id: 5e98255f1c9d440000eefaf5,
        company_name: 'Google',
        board_posts: [ 
            {
                _id: 5e98255f1c9d440000ee5555,
                column_index: 0,
            },
            {
                _id: 5e98255f1c9d440000ee9999,
                column_index: 0,
            },
        ] 
    },
    { 
        _id: 5e98255f1c9d440000eefa44,
        company_name: 'Samsung',
        board_posts: [ 
            {
                _id: 5e98255f1c9d440000ee1111,
                column_index: 0,
            },
            {
                _id: 5e98255f1c9d440000ee2222,
                column_index: 0,
            },
        ] 
    },
]
```

Filtering:

```
    const compId = '5e98255f1c9d440000eefaf5';
    const postId = '5e98255f1c9d440000ee9999';
    const newColumn = req.body.newColumn;

    Company.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                _id: ObjectId(compId),
            },
        },
        {
            $project: {
                board_posts: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$board_posts",
                        as: "post",
                        cond: {
                            $eq: ["$$post._id", ObjectId(postId)],
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    ])
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result[0].board_posts);
        res.sendStatus(201);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to update based on multiple conditions, try this:

```
Company.update({
        _id:"company id",
        board_posts: { $elemMatch:{
            _id: "post id",
        }}
    },
    {
        "$set" : {"board_posts.$.column_index" : "index"}
    }
);
```

**Update #1:** Based on your comment to update multiple fields at once, the method you have specified wouldn't be acceptable syntax for the MongoDB driver.

You can however update them individually like so:

```
Company.update({
        _id:"company id",
        board_posts: { $elemMatch:{
            _id: "post id",
        }}
    },
    {
        "$set" : {
           "board_posts.$.column_index" : "index", 
           "board_posts.$._id" : "id"
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Say I wanted to update all the fields in the board post not just column_index. Would I be able to replace ```"$set" : {"board_posts.$.column_index" : "index"}```  with  ```$set : {'board_posts.$' : boardPost}``` passing a boardPost object with key value pairs

Comment: Do you mean update the _id & column_index, or update more than one board_post object at a time? - see my update @Reece

Comment: no thats perfect, thanks. Just another question though. If the new value for a key is the exact same as the current does update still update this or just leave it as it is? this require no change to the code I'm just curious

Comment: @Reece If the value to be set is the same, It will find a match, but will not perform any modifications: 'WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })'

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E])

```
Company.update(
    {
         _id: ObjectId(compId)
    },
    {
        "$set" : {
             "board_posts.$[elem].column_index" : newIndex
        }
    },
    {
       arrayFilters: [{"elem._id": ObjectId(postId)}]
    }
);
```